# Angular UI-Bootstrap how to get date from DatePicker?

Tags: datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

Given the pop-up example at http://plnkr.co/edit/idrirF9zxvCMCQWTk8nr?p=preview  how do I actually get the date if  the user changes it?

I am guessing that I should do it in `$scope.open = function($event)` but I just don't know how. I have searched this site & googled extensively. What did I miss? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you plunk link is not working.
I don't know what exactly happen in your code.

I think maybe your miss ng-model,
ng-model is the way to do two-way data binding in angular .

for example

```
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt" />
```

in this example date is binding to dt (ng-model="dt")

you can get data by $scope.dt
if you want to watch the date change
you can do

```
$scope.$watch('dt',function(val){
   //to do       
   console.log(val)
})
```